# sqlalchemy - join MySQL table with .csv file

Tags: python, mysql, database, csv, sqlalchemy

I am building a Flask app and I use sqlalchemy to access a MySQL database. This database contains all user logins. The database looks like:

```
LoginID (the primary key) | Username | JoinTime | LeaveTime
```

Please keep in mind that a username can be found in many rows (different logins of a user at different times or days).

I need to generate some stats about the login location, but location data are only available in a `Users.csv` file which contains two columns: `username` and `location` for each user.

I would like to make a join between my database table and the Users.csv file, based on the username.

I have an sqlalchemy query which returns the users that logged in between two given dates:

```
logins = db_session.query(Logins.Username). \
    filter(Logins.JoinTime >= session['start_date']). \
    filter(Logins.LeaveTime <= session['end_date']). \
    all()
```

Is it possible to modify the above query and join the database table with the the Users.csv file? 
I would like a list of user logins with their locations to be returned.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `numpy` library's `genfromtxt` method for loading the *csv* file's content as a `list`.

```
from numpy import genfromtxt

def fetch_data(file_name):
    data = genfromtxt(file_name, delimiter=',', skiprows=1, converters={0: lambda s: str(s)})
    return data.tolist()
```

Now, you can either use this `list` directly with your SQL query or persist the `list` to a separate table in your MySQL database and then use the traditional `JOIN` clause.

Comment: My question was not about transforming the csv to a list (or a dictionary which might be a better option). My questions was how the sqlalchemy query will look in that case. I cannot find any examples of `join` with lists.

Comment: Generally you get tools that help you query data in csv file directly like in SQL. There are however very less libraries that provide you with libraries to query data directly from csv file in python. One of them however is [this](https://github.com/harelba/q/blob/generic-injected-streams/PYTHON-API.markdown)